# Java, defining a method

Tags: java, methods

I'm new to programming....Not sure how to add / define the methods to get the lower half of the program to work.

```
import static java.lang.System.out;
import java.text.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;

public class Dates 
{
    // --- add methods here to make the program work --- //

// ATTEMPTED SOLUTION FOR nameFormat METHOD!!!!!!
```

//Keep getting "cannot find symbol - variable nameFormat
   //or cannot convert string to int error if give a return value
   //have scoured the internet for examples and can't figure this out.

```
    public static int nameFormat(int year, int month, int day)
     {
        SimpleDateFormat nameFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy, MM, dd");
        Date date = nameFormat.parse("2014, 10, 4");
        SimpleDateFormat sdfDestination = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMMM dd, yyyy");

        return nameformat < not sure what to put here;
    }

    public static void printDate(int year, int month, int day) {
        out.println(nameFormat(year, month, day));
        out.println(slashFormat(year, month, day));
        out.println(dashFormat(year, month, day));
        out.println();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        printDate(2014, 10, 4);
        printDate(2015, 1, 1);
        printDate(2013, 12, 31);
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, you need to create methods for `nameFormat(int, int, int)`, `slashFormat(int, int, int)` and `dashFormat(int, int, int)` the same way you created `printDate(int, int, int)`

Comment: This sounds like a school task of some sort...

Comment: There are a lot of examples on the Internet about simple codes with methods. Look at them, try to create your own methods and if you have some doubt, come here again. Good luck!

Comment: @Tawcharowsky Just to be clear: homework questions are OK here as long as they show attempts to solve it and include description of problem which stops OP from finishing it. Unfortunately this is not case here.

Comment: Hi. This is a practice exercise.....trying to teach my self Java. I appreciate the help and feed back. I will try to keep my future question in line with the rules of the site. Thx!

Answer (score 0):

Look here for understanding how a method works: http://mathbits.com/MathBits/Java/Methods/Lesson1.htm

Generally, this is how a method is defined:

```
  public static int functionName(int a, int b ...) {
 // put what you want your method to do.
 return (something);
       }
```